# Balun for impedance matching?

Tags: impedance-matching, balun

I would like to match the output impedance of amplifier IC (1.5 + j1.7) with an antenna of impedance (50 or 75 Ohms) at around 950 MHz.
I thought of using a balun so that I could avoid the inductor and capacitor.There are 1:1 or 1:4 or 1:10 or 1:16 impedance conversion baluns. But here I have complex impedance at the source.
Could any one recommend how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shunt capacitor to make the output impedance of the amplifier real, and then use a proper balun to achieve 50 or 75 ohms.

[image]

Comment: Moni, do you need any clarification?